# Function arity as a result of default parameters in elixir making dialyzer complain

Tags: elixir, dialyzer

I have a function with 2 default parameters

`defp foo(bar, baz, qux \\ "", garply \\ nil)`

I’ve got two usages, one supplies only the first two parameters, the other all 4. Dialyzer is complaining that `Function foo/3 will never be called`. I assume this is because it's private and the two defaults allow for `unroll_nodes/2`, `unroll_nodes/3`, and `unroll_nodes/4`. I could ostensibly drop the defaults and supply them in the current `foo/2` invocation, but it seems silly just to placate dialyzer. Is there a way to specify this in the spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress the dialyzer warning using the `@dialyzer` attribute:

```
@dialyzer {:no_unused, [foo: 3]}
```

All possible options are listed [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html).

Comment: does that mean there's no better way to specify the typespec? it truly is an errant warning? or is this a codesmell?

Comment: I guess that's a combination of Elixir always generating all the intermediate heads. An alternative could be to define the defaults "manually" with a separate function call. Then you'd have only the /2 and /4 versions without the /3 version.